# Referencing assembly targeting 4.5.2 from .csproj targeting 4.5.1 gives error

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, upgrade

I have a library targeting `4.5.2`. When I am referencing this library from `.csproj` targeting `4.5.1`, it errors out saying :

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5):
>   warning MSB3274: The primary reference "XXX, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved
>   because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"
>   framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted
>   framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1".

Per my understanding, `4.5.1` to `4.5.2` is in place upgrade. By in place upgrade I understand that if I upgrade my `.csproj` to `4.5.2` and when my target deployment machine still have `4.5.1`, everything should work fine unless my upgraded binaries making use of specific features of `4.5.2` which is not available in `4.5.1`. Am i correct so far ? Going with similar logic, if I am referencing library targeting `4.5.2` from project targeting `4.5.1`, shouldn't it work ?

Comment: Microsoft makes a lot of effort to ensure that new framework versions are backwards compatible.  You are however asking for forward compatibility, the kind of feature that requires them building a time machine.  They only exist in books and movies.  Updating the user's framework version should never be a problem, having to support a user that refuses to enable Windows Update is a problem you can't get help with here.  It almost always is an imaginary problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because it is an in-place upgrade doesn't mean that you can reference forward versions. Ultimately, the package you want to reference is 4.5.2, which means it can be making use of features that *only exist* in 4.5.2. Because of this, it is *not safe* to target it from a 4.5.1 project, because the entire point of saying "I target 4.5.1" is so that if someone *has* 4.5.1, *it should run*. Which: this wouldn't.

So: if you want to target a package that currently targets 4.5.2, you have two choices:

- change your project to target 4.5.2
- see whether the package you want to reference could be tweaked to target 4.5.1 (either instead of, or in addition to, 4.5.2)

Comment: Thanks Marc !! I understand your point from safety perspective. But isn't it possible to run application targeting 4.5.2 on machine having 4.5.1 ? (Provided application is not making any use of 4.5.2 feature)

Comment: @RahulAgarwal there's no reason to expect that to work, no; it *might* work, but that would be a convenience, not a reasonable expectation. If you want something to work on 4.5.1: target 4.5.1

Comment: Thanks Marc !! Agree. I asked just out of curiosity. Also I believe your answer _it might work_ is solely because 4.5.1 to 4.5.2 is in place upgrade, right ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal "in place upgrade" is probably a red herring; I wouldn't obsess too much about that, to be honest